# Code not on BS4, but can be found in 'Inspect Element'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have tried making a website which uses Beautiful Soup 4 to search g2a for the prices of games (by class). The problem is that when I look in the HTML code, it clearly shows the price of the first result (£2.30), but when I search for the class in Beautiful Soup 4, there is nothing between the same class's tags:

[image: http://prnt.sc/ehltnf]

[image: http://prnt.sc/ehltwg]

```
#summoningg2a
r = requests.get('https://www.g2a.com/?search=x')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

#finding prices
prices = soup.find_all("strong", class_="mp-pi-price-min")

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: wrt. screenshots -- one shows `mp-pi-price-min` while the other `mp-pi-price` those are different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests` doesn't handle dynamic page content. You're best bet is using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to drive a browser. From there you can parse `page_source` with BeautifulSoup to get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome development tools, you can check the ajax request(made by Javascript) URL. you can mimic that requests and get data back.

```
r = requests.get('the ajax requests url')
data = r.text
```

[image]